# How can a phishing page know my account information?

Tags: phishing

I clicked on a phishing website. I was surprised to find that this website looked exactly like google and had my information displayed. The information displayed were my email and my profile picture. I quickly left the website without knowing what to do. Can someone access my google account even if I changed the password?

I use the same password for a lot of websites. (more than 150)

Do I have to change that password for all the websites?

Comment: I used a website that checks if a website is phishing. I was maybe wrong thinking that the website got my information. It seems like that website was only redirecting to google. What caught my eye was that the redirection lead to a http page instead of https. I don't know if information can leak that way.

I changed the passwords on all the accounts that I cared about with the help of a password manager. And I'm trying to delete the accounts I don't use anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the top-level question, lots of possibilities here:

- It was an actual Google login page, aiming to get you to do something (like grant access to a malicious service) other than steal your credentials.
- The picture was the same HTML img tag that Google uses on their own login page, which naturally retrieved your picture when used with your browser (cross-domain loading of images is normal and generally allowed).
- It was content overlaid on the Google page, probably using an iframe. This is probably not the case, as Google blocks iframes on most sensitive pages.
- You had shared information (including name, picture, email address, etc.) with a third-party site (such as a forum, social media, or so on) and that information was used to create the phishing page.
- You had communicated with, or at least allowed communication with, the attacker over some network (such as Google Hangouts or Skype or something) that displays an image and your email address.
- The attacker guessed your information on the basis of your email address and/or name, if they had that from elsewhere or were just able to guess it.

Several of these can be combined (for example, the second bullet - using Google's usual image link - might combine with knowing your email address from a third-party site).

---

> I use the same password for a lot of websites. (more than 150)
>
> Do I have to change that password for all the websites?

## YES!

I cannot stress strongly enough how terrible an idea it is to repeat the same password across so many sites! That is *ESPECIALLY* true if it includes sensitive sites (like your email account, which can usually be used to reset the password for anything else) and also casual, low-sensitivity ones (which, if you have over 100, it almost certainly does)!

To be clear, this isn't because you visited a phishing page. Just clicking the link, but leaving before you entered anything, is usually not a disaster. It's not even because the page had your account info; that's concerning but not hugely so (see the first part of the answer). This is because ***re-using passwords is never a good idea***.

What happens if one of the sites gets compromised? Have you checked https://haveibeenpwned.com/ to see if your account was ever breached? If so, they got all your sites!

What happens if one of the sites you used has an untrustworthy administrator or is straight-up malicious? Allow XKCD to illustrate this for me: https://xkcd.com/792/

So... how do you avoid password reuse, when you've got so many sites?

#### Use a password manager

There are multiple good ones out there. LastPass and 1Password are probably the best known, but there are others (this site discourages recommending specific products). Password managers have all kinds of good properties:

- They remember, and can auto-fill, any number of unique passwords (even multiple passwords for one site, if needed).
- They can generate random passwords (humans are terrible at this).
- They keep a record of all your accounts so you never have to wonder whether you have one, or what its info was.
- They can store other info beyond just passwords, like usernames and those BS "security question" answers.
- They can even store payment card info and other secrets like that.
- They can report when passwords are re-used across sites (again: THIS IS VERY BAD).
- They can securely share passwords (or other items) between users, if you need to e.g. share your password to a particular account with your spouse.

---

One last thing:

#### Turn on multi-factor authentication

Many sites - especially security-conscious ones - let you use multiple factors (not just a password) when you log in. This means that *even if somebody gets your password* they still can't log in as you! Very important. There are lots of choices for the second factor (passwords are still usually the first). The better forms of MFA can even protect against phishing pages.

In order of increasing quality:

- SMS or phone call - weak (it's easy to hijack phone numbers), but better than nothing.
- TOTP (Google Authenticator and the like) - can be kind of a hassle but decently secure and widely supported.
- One-time codes from an external device (like a Yubikey or RSA authenticator) - sometimes more convenient than TOTP apps, possibly harder to steal.
- Push notification to an app - not widely supported, but more convenient and pretty secure.
- U2F / FIDO2 from the browser/machine - can protect against phishing attacks, very convenient if you always use the same device (or small number of devices) and they support it.
- U2F / FIDO2 from an external device (Yubikey or similar) - protects against phishing, very secure, usually pretty convenient, not super common yet but getting better.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create passwords that are the same from the start, if you need help you could use LastPass or Dashlane, but remember to set a good master password! Also, if you know how to use APIs from Google, you can get your Gmail, username and profile pictures. you should not be clicking on phishing links anyways, because they could have a drive-by download of malware.

Comment: While what you say is not wrong you don't actually address the specific questions asked, i.e. *"Can someone access my google account even if I changed the password?"* and *"Do I have to change that password for all the websites?"*.